# FCM gettoken() stopped working, returning DOM versionerror

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to get the token of my current device via firebase cloud messaging. I am using the following code:

```js
 messaging.getToken().then(function(refreshedToken) {
    console.log("success ",refreshedToken);
 }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Unable to retrieve refreshed token ', err);
  });
```

I then registered the device as part of a device group for one of my users(as per the firebase documentation). Now, however, whenever I try to get my device token, I get the following error: "The operation failed because the stored database is a higher version than the version requested." I tried clearing local history, but that didn't help. I also tried switching browsers. I don't know what the "stored database" even is. Is there any way to fix this? thanks!

Comment: Can you check to see if you have requested permissions for messaging?

Comment: Yes, I just made sure that I have permission, but still no token

Comment: I've never come across the error you are seeing. Are you certain this error is caused because of firebase messaging or some other library trying to do a local storage?

Comment: I'm not sure, although I do know that the error is returned by the above function. What would you recommend in terms of diagnosing this?

Comment: If messaging fails, the console.log should print `Unable to retrieve with the error`. I would suggest to only use `messaging.getToken().then(function(currentToken) {
      if (currentToken) {
        console.log(currentToken);
      } else {
        console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
      }
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
    });`